# How to invoke a python script on AWS EFS from a Lambda Function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

Can I invoke a python script on AWS EFS from a lambda function?

I have already mounted my lambda function to an EFS and am able to access & read files from it. I am also able to import python libraries that I installed on EFS.

Here is a sample Lambda function that is working -

```py
import json
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/mnt/access')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    print(np.zeros(3))
    
    data = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B":[4, 5 , 6]})
    print(data.head())
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Now I want to pass some payload from lambda to a python script on EFS which would then do some processing and pass the result back to lambda.

Is this possible?  How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried `os.system("python /path/to/<your-script>.py")` or ``os.system("python3 /path/to/<your-script>.py")``?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a sensible way to use AWS Lambda. Can you put the code in a normal Lambda function, but the data on EFS?

Comment: What do you mean? Which data are you talking about?